# Runtime Error when assigning cell values between sheets.

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set cell values from one sheet to another in a work book, and I get a runtime '1004 error. Application defined or object defined error.

```
Worksheet("Display").Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 2)).Value =  Worksheets("Pm Types").Range(Cells(i + 2, 1), Cells(i + 2, 2)).Value
```

If I split this by first assigning it to a variable, then activating the second sheet, then assigning the variable to the cell I do not get an error. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Guessing you need to qualify the `cells`.

Comment: Of course.. Simple solution, Thanks!